# PHP7.2.9 Illegal String Problem on Localhost

Tags: php, apache, localhost, php-7.2

I am getting "Illegal String" problem on Localhost.

But I know, this problem becase of new PHP version which is PHP 7+.

So, in this version something has been changed. For example,

We can't use this method in PHP7 anymore:

```
$array = $something;
$array['value'] = 'something';
```

We have to use it like this :

```
$array = (array) $something;
$array['value'] = 'something';
```

Also, on my server I have PHP 7 but, old method is working on server fine. I am not getting any error. Why don't work it in my localhost? **Do you have any idea about it?**

**My Server PHP Version Details:**

```
*PHP 7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2018 07:16:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 
Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies*
```

**My Localhost PHP Version Details:**

```
*PHP 7.2.9 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2018 23:29:19) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x86 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies*
```

Comment: "_We can't use this method in PHP7 anymore:_" We can't?

Comment: if `$something` is not an array, you should not be assigning it to `$array` in the first place if `$array` is supposed to be an array. So if it can be `null` or an empty string, you should probably use something like this to assign a value: `$array = $something ?: [];`

Comment: @kerbholz Indeed we can't. `$something = "hello"; $array = $something; $array["value"] = "someDatas";` -> Illegal string offset 'value'

Comment: I suspect `$something` is a string, therefore `'value'` is not a valid index - hence *Illegal string offset 'value'*. You *can* access strings by index, incidentally: `$something = "this is a string"; $something[2] = "X";` outputs `thXs is a string`

Comment: @Cid Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Yes guys, you are right, but I am getting problem only on localhost

@Cid $array["value"] = "someDatas"; this method doesn't give me any error on server. only I am getting problem on localhost. I don't know why

Comment: @jeroen I wouldn't ! I just discovered that new behaviour reading the question and answering kerbholz comment

Comment: @Cid Sorry, I assumed you were the original poster :-)

Comment: @Cid I think the important part in your example is `$something = "hello";`, which is missing in OPs question.

Comment: @kerbholz yep I had to figure it out